# Values in scope not visible in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple controller:

```
module.exports = require('angular')
.module('HomeModule', [])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.someValue = 10;
    console.log($scope.someValue);

});
```

and a simple view:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="banner" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Name</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#1">{{someValue}}</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Function#2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">Function#3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

When this header html is loaded in the browser I can see 10 value printed in the console, however, the value is not visible on the page. Any ideas why **someValue** is not visible in the html template?

Comment: I assume no errors in the console and you have `ng-app` decalred somewhere?

Comment: Did you declare `ng-app` anywhere in your HTML?

Comment: Yes, in my layout I have <body ng-app="AppModule">, and in a separate script file I have: 
var angular = require('angular'),
 app = angular.module('AppModule', [
  'CommonModule',
  'HomeModule'
 ]);

Comment: Do you have any other directives in the HTML you posted - perhaps with an isolated scope?  Try {{$parent.someValue}} - does that fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There was one piece missing from the picture. The html template was interpreted by dust library. It appeared that dust interprets {} on its own why, hence angular had no way to "see" {{}}.
In order to mitigate this ng-bind can be used.